# CPU-and-memory efficient NGram extraction with R

Tags: r, performance, text-mining, n-gram

I wrote an algorithm which extract NGrams (bigrams, trigrams, ... till 5-grams) from a list of 50000 street addresses. My goal is to have for each address a boolean vector representing whether the NGrams are present or not in the address. Therefor each address will be characterized by a vector of attributes, and then I can carry out a clustering on the addresses. 
The algo works that way : 
I start with the bi-grams, I calculate all the combinations of (a-z and 0-9 and / and tabulation) : for example : aa,ab,ac,...,a8,a9,a/,a ,ba,bb,...
Then I carry out a loop for each address and extract for all the bigrams the information 0 or 1 (bi-gram not present or present). 
Afterward, I calculate for the bigrams that occur the most the trigrams. 
And so on ...
My problem is the time that the algo takes to run. Another problem : R reach its maximal capacity when there are more than 10000 NGrams. It's obvious because a 50000*10000 matrice is huge.
I need your ideas to optimize the algo or to change it. Thank you.

Comment: In the extraction I also consider the tabulation for instance : avenue foch = ..., "e f",...

Comment: Consider trying the **quanteda** package, using `tokenize(mytext, ngrams = 1:5)`. To create a matrix you can use `dfm(mytext, ngrams = 1:5)`. If you supply a sample of your address texts, I will produce an answer demonstrating this.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. For instance I have this address "1780 wemmel" and I wanna extract : _1 17 78 80 0_ _w we em mm me el l_ and _17 178 780 80_ 0_w _we wem emm mme mel el_ and _178 1780 780_ 80_w 0_we _wem wemm emme mmel mel_ and _1780 1780_ 780_w 80_we 0_wem _wemm wemme emmel mmel_

Comment: There are already at least(!) 5 R packages doing ngrams, for the love of God please pick the one you find most performant and contribute to making it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `quanteda` package, using this method.  If you just want tokenized texts, replace the `dfm(` with `tokenize(`.

I'd be **very** interested to know how it works on your 50,000 street addresses.  We've put a lot of effort into making `dfm()` very fast and robust.

```
myDfm <- dfm(c("1780 wemmel", "2015 schlemmel"), what = "character", 
             ngram = 1:5, concatenator = "", 
             removePunct = FALSE, removeNumbers = FALSE, 
             removeSeparators = FALSE, verbose = FALSE)
t(myDfm) # for easier viewing
#         docs
# features text1 text2
#           1     1
# s         0     1
# sc        0     1
# sch       0     1
# schl      0     1
# w         1     0
# we        1     0
# wem       1     0
# wemm      1     0
# 0         1     1
# 0         1     0
# 0 w       1     0
# 0 we      1     0
# 0 wem     1     0
# 01        0     1
# 015       0     1
# 015       0     1
# 015 s     0     1
# 1         1     1
# 15        0     1
# 15        0     1
# 15 s      0     1
# 15 sc     0     1
# 17        1     0
# 178       1     0
# 1780      1     0
# 1780      1     0
# 2         0     1
# 20        0     1
# 201       0     1
# 2015      0     1
# 2015      0     1
# 5         0     1
# 5         0     1
# 5 s       0     1
# 5 sc      0     1
# 5 sch     0     1
# 7         1     0
# 78        1     0
# 780       1     0
# 780       1     0
# 780 w     1     0
# 8         1     0
# 80        1     0
# 80        1     0
# 80 w      1     0
# 80 we     1     0
# c         0     1
# ch        0     1
# chl       0     1
# chle      0     1
# chlem     0     1
# e         2     2
# el        1     1
# em        1     1
# emm       1     1
# emme      1     1
# emmel     1     1
# h         0     1
# hl        0     1
# hle       0     1
# hlem      0     1
# hlemm     0     1
# l         1     2
# le        0     1
# lem       0     1
# lemm      0     1
# lemme     0     1
# m         2     2
# me        1     1
# mel       1     1
# mm        1     1
# mme       1     1
# mmel      1     1
# s         0     1
# sc        0     1
# sch       0     1
# schl      0     1
# schle     0     1
# w         1     0
# we        1     0
# wem       1     0
# wemm      1     0
# wemme     1     0
```

Comment: Ken, can you post benchmarks of quanteda vs tm+RWeka , both for CPU and memory?

Answer (score -1):

Some of these problems are, to an extent, already solved by the `tm` library and `RWeka` (for n-gram tokenization). Have a look at those, they might make your task easier.

For running out of memory I see two options:

1. `tm` uses sparse matrices, which are an efficient way of storing matrices with many zero elements.
2. You could also look at the `bigmemory` package. Although, I've never used it http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html

There's lots of ways of speeding up R code. Here's a guide to some of the ways of doing it: http://www.r-bloggers.com/faster-higher-stonger-a-guide-to-speeding-up-r-code-for-busy-people/

Comment: This is at best a comment! Please provide working solutions in the answer!