# Memory-efficient ways to extract word nGrams in R

Tags: r, performance, memory, n-gram

I've been using the `ngram` function(`ngram` package, same name) to produce some simple ngrams on some text data.  The reason I am looking for alternatives is how the ngram class object is stored is killing my memory.

What I have is a data frame that has two columns uniqueid, texttoparse

Example

1         a bit of text

2         some more text

3         even more to review

```
w6$ngram <- sapply(w6$texttoparse,ngram)
w6$actNgram <- as.character(sapply(w6$ngram,get.ngrams))
```

gives me the following ngrams

1  a bit of text // a bit // bit of // of text

2 some more text // some more // more text

3 even more to review // even more // more to // to review

my problem is, the ngram and actNgram fields while displaying correctly appear to have pointers and references to every row in my data frame.  This makes them massive and unwieldy.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ngram/ngram.pdf

even mentions the ngram container impacts the ability to save or load data.

Is there another way I can get to this output?

Comment: Duplicate of [CPU-and-memory efficient NGram extraction with R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424687/cpu-and-memory-efficient-ngram-extraction-with-r)

Comment: The solution provided by this potential duplicate operates at the character level not individual word level.  In the 4 months since I asked this question I moved on to developing the ngrams in google big query since it was available to me at the time.

Comment: No, actually `quanteda::tokenize()` does word tokenization too. There are several R packages doing word tokenization.